# How does the "-newer $file" option of "find" command in linux shell work?

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have following linux command.

```
find ${MOUNT_POINT} -type f -name "VM*" -newer $SENTFILE -print0 | xargs -0 -i cp {} ${TMP_DIR}
```

I am having difficulty understanding the option `-newer $SENTFILE`. Could anybody explain this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man find`:

```
-newer file
    File  was  modified  more recently than file.  If file is a sym‐
    bolic link and the -H option or the -L option is in effect,  the
    modification time of the file it points to is always used.
```

Comment: So, how should I prepare in $SENTFILE? I mean I have to record previous file name or file creation date in $SENTFILE?

Comment: What do you mean by "prepare"? The find command will simply return only files, that are newer than the file in the variable `$SENTFILE`.

Comment: I would like to know one point, Do you mean there will be old file date like this "2017/07/25" in variable $SENTFILE?? Otherwise ,what is it?

Comment: `$SENTFILE` is another file. If the `find` command finds a file that is *older* than the one in `$SENTFILE`, it will *not* show it. If it finds a file that is *newer* than the one in `$SENTFILE`, it will show it.

Answer (score 1):

If `$SENTFILE` is expanded with spaces, you might have bad things (several arguments passed to `find`). I would recommend quoting it like

```
 find ${MOUNT_POINT} -type f -name "VM*" -newer "$SENTFILE" -print0 \
```

Otherwise, `-newer` works like [pfnuesel answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24927970/841108). I guess that `find` is using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (then comparing the `st_mtime` fields for `-newer`)

Of course, your `SENTFILE` is set by the invoking shell (or some outer script). It should contain the name of some file.

If this is part of some shell script, try debugging that shell script, perhaps by having

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
```

as its first line or add something like

```
echo SENTFILE is $SENTFILE 2>&1
```

or maybe (see [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html), then look in your system log files, probably under `/var/log/`)

```
logger -s SENTFILE is $SENTFILE
```

You are not familiar enough with basic shell scripting. So read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) or something better.